# save layout back into xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on a project where I have multiple tabs, and I want the content of each tab to be set dynamically based on what is selected in the previous tab. (For my tabs, I am using the `SlidingTabLayout` with a `ViewPager`). I currently have my first tab set up correctly and have it tied to an `EventBus` that creates a `LinearLayout` based off of my template from `R.layouts.tab_2` and adds the content dynamically. What I can't quite figure out is how to save my `LinearLayout` back into the `tab_2.xml` file. I have seen suggestions of saving it with `SharedPreferences`, but that doesn't allow me to save it as the right file type.

If there is a much easier way to do this, such as updating the tab that is already created, I am open to that instead of saving the layout back into the `XML` file. I am fairly new at programming in *Android Studio* and still trying to get the basics down.

Comment: You don't save layouts into an xml file programatically.  There's no mechanism for doing so.  They aren't even xml files by the time you pack them into an apk, they're pre-compiled for efficiency.

Comment: Is there a better way of saving the layout or sending it over to a fragment that has already been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first tab, as I'm interpreting it, is essentially a settings page. The user does a few things, and as a result of those things - the layout on your second tab looks different.

You need to save some variables based on user interactions. For example, if you have a checkbox the user is going to press - you would set a boolean to true when they've checked it, and false when they've unchecked it. When the user navigates to your second tab, you will check the value of that boolean - and alter that layout accordingly.

Hopefully this concept will, even in its simplicity - help you understand how apps are built to be functional.

Comment: I totally get the concept behind object-oriented programming. I have been writing applications in C# for years. From the logic standpoint I know about 5 ways to do what I want, but I just started using Android Studio last week and I'm still trying to figure out the flow of everything.

I have tried to check those values when the Fragment is created, but I get an error because it is being created before there is any user input. I tried an onFocusChanged listener, but it never triggered when I changed the tab. I guess what I need is how to update the tab when it gains focus.

Comment: I removed that part of my post.

In regards to what you're saying, I would look into the Fragment lifecycle to have a better understanding of how that works. In a ViewPager, I believe the fragments are re-inflated on swipe - meaning you'll need to store those variables in an active area, like the encompassing activity. You can also extend the application class and store variables globally in there.

Comment: Thanks Evan. The fragment isn't re-inflating itself on swipe (or at least not going through what I have in `onCreateView`), but at least I am headed in the right direction.

Comment: Ok cool, in that case you'll want to just override `onResume()` and update your layout inside there. Glad you figured it out.